# Mosquitto - have a log with IP of topic client

Tags: logging, ip, mosquitto

I need help in order to understand witch component in my house have sent specific topic.

So my first idea is to have in some log file,
the IP of every client message topic
Is this possible please ?

I just try verbose with "mosquitto -v" but only think I see is msg. like:

```
1609839026: Received PUBLISH from 5KX5TJ8paygKIlVqvzLZhI (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'luce.garage/cmnd/POWER', ... (2 bytes))
```

But I can't understand who is "5KX5TJ8paygKIlVqvzLZhI" client.
So is possible to have a log with client topic IP please ?

Thanks in advance
Denis

Comment: In the logs you see the client id which was used when connecting to the broker. If you omit the client id when connecting, mosquitto will generate a random one (obviously what happened in your case). So just use the IP address as client id

Comment: Great idea thanks a lot... Now I just must to understand how to give ClienID to all cliente around my home. Thanks again